# There is a CPU spike once per hour when logging "TraceLedgerEvent.TookSnapshot". Is it a bug, or is there a fix?

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-node

About once an hour, when `TraceLedgerEvent.TookSnapshot` is written to the log, there is a CPU spike and at the same time the `slotMissedNum` is increasing. Is this a bug in the node? Or is there a fix?

cardano-node v1.27.0
CPU 6Core
Mem 16GB
[image]

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community and thank you so much for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Please take a look at the edits that I suggested since they may improve how well your question is received here.

Answer (score 2):

That CPU usage spike is only at most 8% of the CPU capacity, which is extremely small. I get spikes on my laptop CPU of 100% for longer time intervals than the spikes here, when just casually browsing the web.

If anything is being written anywhere on the computer, or anything is happening such as `slotMissedNum` increasing, I would  expect a CPU usage spike of around the size of the extremely small spikes you're seeing here.

I hope that takes care of the CPU spikes part of the question. If you believe that the increasing of `slotMissedNum` is a bug, then that's a different matter, for which I'm not immediately able to offer a solution, but that bug can be addressed entirely independently since the CPU spikes do not create any ***additional*** concerns.

Comment: Some of you have pointed out the same problem, what do you think?

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/2731

Comment: To clarify on the above answer, this spike occurs when it rights the state of the ledger in memory to disk at an interval. As the above comment states, it's a very small spike. If we didn't do this periodically, you'd have to rebuild the entire ledger state from scratch every restart of the node.

Comment: I think you mean, as the above ***answer*** indicates.